# How do I reference a string from a cell in a Google Spreadsheet formula?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet that I use to track progress completion based on the percentage of checkboxes that are TRUE (checked).

The formula I use for this has 3 separate references to another sheet. I do this for every project and I am looking into reducing the amount of copy and pasting I am doing when adding a new tracker. Currently I am using the below formula:

```
=COUNTIF('Automation: PHP Reference Parser'!A:A,TRUE)/(COUNTIF('Automation: 
PHP Reference Parser'!A:A, FALSE)+COUNTIF('Automation: PHP Reference 
Parser'!A:A, TRUE))
```

I am trying to replace the three instances of 'Automation: PHP Reference Parser' with a reference to a cell that already contains this string as the project name. I have attempted to do this with INDIRECT but I get a parse error in the following attempt:

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT(A2)!A:A,TRUE)/(COUNTIF(INDIRECT(A2)!A:A, FALSE)+COUNTIF(INDIRECT(A2)!A:A, TRUE))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your

```
INDIRECT(A2)!A:A
```

to the following format.

```
INDIRECT(A2&"!A:A")
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!